# How to use debugger to generate a trace file?

Tags: python, debugging, trace, instrumentation

My work is to instrument a python application such that it generates a trace file consisting of the necessary dynamic information. I am using a python script to instrument the source code. I have achieved by inserting lots of statements into the source code and successively generated a trace file.

My question is, is there a way to use the debugger as such to generate the traces file?

If so could anyone give me one example of how would you insert a print statement in any of the function during debugging?

Comment: Do you mean UnitTesting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python trace module for this purpose. It shows all running code

[Trace all statements from a point in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706614/trace-all-statements-from-a-point-in-code)

You can also insert print statements, but then you have to remember to clean them up afterwards. Comma-seperate the parms you which to print.

```
print 'logpoint 1, vals: ', vals
```